# Why does this vba MsgBox always return zero?

Tags: vba

I have a VBA `MsgBox` with `vbYesNo` as the button-type but no matter what button is pushed it always shows a return result as zero. Sorry this isn't the entire code but the below code is a portion of the code that is giving me trouble.

```
Sub testMsg()

Dim strCheckFolders As Integer ' <== vbyesno MsgBoxResult (7 = no, 6 = yes)
Dim RunThis As Boolean

RunThis = True

Do Until RunThis = False
    If strCheckFolders = MsgBox("Do you want to check folders for reports to print?", _
    vbYesNo, "Check for Reports to Print") = vbNo Then RunThis = False
Loop

End Sub
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is write this loop without using the standard phrase `if x=vbNo then Exit Sub`. I'd rather try to let it run it's course. But that would only work if `MsgBox` could change the value of `RunThis` to `False`.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=` is used both as an assignment operator and a comparison operator in VBA. You can't assign and compare in a single statement (at least not without the unexpected results you're getting). Separate the assignment from the comparison:

```
Do Until RunThis = False
    strCheckFolders = MsgBox("Do you want to check folders for reports to print?", vbYesNo, "Check for Reports to Print")
    If strCheckFolders = vbNo Then RunThis = False
Loop
```

You could even remove the need for `strCheckFolders` altogether:

```
Do Until RunThis = False
    If MsgBox("Do you want to check folders for reports to print?", vbYesNo, _
        "Check for Reports to Print") = vbNo Then RunThis = False
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks @Bond that works. I realize now what was going on. Actually now I have your first answer as the method I'm using. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would place the MsgBox in an if statement. Then based on the result do an action

```
Do Until RunThis = False
If MsgBox("Do you want to check folders for reports to print?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
    RunThis = False
End If
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: That's actually the same answer as above. No difference, except that you added "End If" on a separate line and you wouldn't really need to do that if you don't have another "Else" statement. I was looking for the shortest solution and the one marked as the solution(by Bond) is the best one offered.